# Parsing XML with VB.NET with LINQ To XML

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq-to-xml

I have an incoming XML stream from a web service response that looks like so

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<HotelPropertyDescriptionRS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" TimeStamp="2013-12-30T18:49:36" Version="1.14.1">
  <Success xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2003/07" />
  <RoomStay xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2003/07">
    <RoomRates>
      <RoomRate GuaranteeSurchargeRequired="G" IATACharacteristicIdentification="BGGO00" IATAProductIdentification="BLOOMBERG" RPH="001">
        <AdditionalInfo>
          <CancelPolicy Numeric="06" />
          <Commission NonCommission="true">NON COMMISSIONABLE</Commission>
          <Text>BLOOMBERG LP, 0.0 KM, INCLUDES BREAKFAST, INTERNET, WIFI, SEE</Text>
          <Text>RATE RULES DELUXE ROOM, GUEST ROOM, 1 KING OR 2 TWIN/SINGLE BE</Text>
        </AdditionalInfo>
        <Rates>
          <Rate Amount="66.600" CurrencyCode="KWD">
            <AdditionalGuestAmounts>
              <AdditionalGuestAmount MaxExtraPersonsAllowed="0">
                <Charges ExtraPerson="0" />
              </AdditionalGuestAmount>
            </AdditionalGuestAmounts>
            <HotelTotalPricing Amount="76.590">
              <Disclaimer>INCLUDES TAXES AND SURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
              <TotalSurcharges Amount="9.990" />
            </HotelTotalPricing>
          </Rate>
        </Rates>
      </RoomRate>
....
```

(there will be many RoomRate values returned. I have created a class to hold the values I need to parse from said XML which looks like so

```
Namespace Classes.Models
    Public Class RoomRate
        Public Property Rate() As String
        Public Property Surcharge() As String
        Public Property TotalPrice() As String
        Public Property CurrencyCode() As String
        Public Property CancellationPolicy() As String
        Public Property Disclaimer() As String
        Public Property Text() As List(Of String)
        Public Property Commission() As String
        Public Property GuaranteeSurchargeRequired() As String
        Public Property IATACharacteristicIdentification() As String
        Public Property IATAProductIdentification() As String
        Public Property RPH() As String
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Now I'm not looking for someone to write all the code for me, I'm more looking for ideas on which would be the most efficient way to parse this into my class. I can use the XPathDocument and XPathNavigation & XPathNodeIterator classes to do this (not 100% sure how they work yet) but is there a better way to accomplish this task?

**EDIT**

I have come up with this so far, which should get me the first attributes in the RoomRate element

```
Return From el As XElement In _xDoc...<RoomRate>
               Select New RoomRate With { _
                   .GuaranteeSurchargeRequired = el...<RoomRate>.@GuaranteeSurchargeRequired, _
                   .IATACharacteristicIdentification = el...<RoomRate>.@IATACharacteristicIdentification, _
                   .IATAProductIdentification = el...<RoomRate>.@IATAProductIdentification, _
                   .RPH = el...<RoomRate>.@RPH}
```

Now how would I traverse to get say the cancellation policy, room rate and other attributes/elements within this code I provided? Sorry for so many questions, I really want to learn this the right way and be able to do it correctly.

**EDIT #2**

I think I'm on the right track here:

```
Return From el As XElement In _xDoc...<RoomRate>
           Select New RoomRate With { _
               .GuaranteeSurchargeRequired = el.@GuaranteeSurchargeRequired, _
               .IATACharacteristicIdentification = el.@IATACharacteristicIdentification, _
               .IATAProductIdentification = el.@IATAProductIdentification, _
               .RPH = el.@RPH, _
               .CancellationPolicy = el...<AdditionalInfo>...<CancellationPolicy>.@Numeric, _
               .Commission = el...<AdditionalInfo>...<Commission>.@NonCommission}
```

Can someone let me know if I'm on the right track for accomplishing this?

**EDIT 3**

I have changed my code to this

```
For Each n As XElement In _xDoc.Elements("RoomRate")
                    _rates.Add(New RoomRate With { _
                               .GuaranteeSurchargeRequired = n.Attribute("GuarateeSurchargeRequired").Value, _
                               .IATACharacteristicIdentification = n.Attribute("IATACharacteristicIdentification").Value, _
                               .IATAProductIdentification = n.Attribute("IATAProductIdentification").Value, _
                               .RPH = n.Attribute("RPH")})
                Next
```

And while I'm no longer getting any errors, but am not getting any results returned as well.

**EDIT 4**
I have made the following changes t my code, which should return an IEnumerable(Of RoomRate) but it's returning nothing (this is based on the XML snippet i posted above)

```
Dim rates = From rate In _xDoc.Descendants("RoomRate")
                Select New RoomRate With { _
                    .GuaranteeSurchargeRequired = rate.Attribute("GuaranteeSurchargeRequired").Value, _
                    .IATACharacteristicIdentification = rate.Attribute("IATACharacteristicIdentification").Value, _
                    .IATAProductIdentification = rate.Attribute("IATAProductIdentification").Value, _
                    .RPH = rate.Attribute("RPH").Value}
```

That looks like it should work, what am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT #5**
@Neolisk I made my changes the way you suggested, it now looks like so

```
For Each n As XElement In _xDoc.Descendants("RoomRate")
    rate = New RoomRate()
    rate.GuaranteeSurchargeRequired = n.Attribute("GuaranteeSurchargeRequired").Value
    rate.IATACharacteristicIdentification = n.Attribute("IATACharacteristicIdentification").Value
    rate.IATAProductIdentification = n.Attribute("IATAProductIdentification")
    _rates.Add(rate)
Next
Return _rates
```

But it never goes into the loop, it goes straight to **Return _rates**

**EDIT #6**

Ok I got it populating the first 3 attributes of the RoomRate element like this

```
Dim rate As RoomRate
Dim ns As XNamespace = "http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2003/07"
Dim rate As RoomRate
For Each n As XElement In _xDoc.Descendants(ns + "RoomRate")
    rate = New RoomRate()
    rate.GuaranteeSurchargeRequired = n.Attribute("GuaranteeSurchargeRequired").Value
    rate.IATACharacteristicIdentification = n.Attribute("IATACharacteristicIdentification").Value
    rate.IATAProductIdentification = n.Attribute("IATAProductIdentification").Value
    rate.RPH = n.Attribute("RPH").Value

    _rates.Add(rate)
Next
```

Now when I try to traverse through the rest of the document I try and get the CancelPolicy value like so

```
Dim rate As RoomRate
Dim ns As XNamespace = "http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2003/07"
Dim rate As RoomRate
For Each n As XElement In _xDoc.Descendants(ns + "RoomRate")
    rate = New RoomRate()
    rate.GuaranteeSurchargeRequired = n.Attribute("GuaranteeSurchargeRequired").Value
    rate.IATACharacteristicIdentification = n.Attribute("IATACharacteristicIdentification").Value
    rate.IATAProductIdentification = n.Attribute("IATAProductIdentification").Value
    rate.RPH = n.Attribute("RPH").Value
    rate.CancellationPolicy = n.Element("AdditionalInfo").Element("CancelPolicy").Attribute("Numeric").Value

    _rates.Add(rate)
Next
```

But adding that last line causes a NullReferenceException. How would I go about going through the XML now?

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? LINQ to XML is much easier than XPathDocument, especially in VB.NET, where you can use XML literals inline.

Comment: Then use LINQ to XML and ignore XPathDocument and XmlDocument.

Comment: I've not used LINQ to XML before, got an example (given the above XML and class) how I would accomplish this with LINQ to XML?

Comment: **Regarding your edit:** I would advise *against* using LINQ in this case, you will have a hard time debugging this if your XML ever changes, or you revise how you retrieve elements. Also don't use VB's LINQ-to-XML shorthand syntax (`...`, `<>`, `@`), better use `Descendant(s)`, `Element(s)` and `Attribute(s)` functions - easier to understand this way. Without picking on the syntax, I think you need to add `.Value` at the end. Always check the retrieved object in debugger. Make sure the types are what you expect to have. I recommend having most simple types possible, i.e. integer, string etc.

Comment: @Neolisk My edit #3 doesn't generate any error any longer, but it's not returning any values. Also, I wanted to take the time to thank you for taking your time to walk me through this.

Comment: I cannot stress this enough it seems. Please rewrite using 1 assignment per line (forget about `Select With` for now). Use `For Each rate As XElement In _xDoc.Descendants("RoomRate")`, don't use LINQ. Then step through with debugger and inspect each property after assignment, see which one is improperly assigned. Post your results.

Comment: I tried that with edit #3, the For Each Loop, and it returns nothing (No Select at all)

Comment: @Neolist I made the changes you suggested, stepped through it and it never goes into the loop so it's always returning nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got my issue resolved with this code

```
Public Function ParseRates() As IEnumerable(Of RoomRate)
    Try
        Dim ns As XNamespace = "http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2003/07"
        Dim rate As RoomRate
        For Each n As XElement In _xDoc.Descendants(ns + "RoomRate")
            _rates.Add(New RoomRate With { _
                        .GuaranteeSurchargeRequired = n.Attribute("GuaranteeSurchargeRequired").Value, _
                        .IATACharacteristicIdentification = n.Attribute("IATACharacteristicIdentification").Value, _
                        .IATAProductIdentification = n.Attribute("IATAProductIdentification").Value, _
                        .RPH = n.Attribute("RPH").Value, _
                        .CancellationPolicy = n.Element(ns + "AdditionalInfo").Element(ns + "CancelPolicy").Attribute("Numeric").Value, _
                        .Commission = n.Element(ns + "AdditionalInfo").Element(ns + "Commission").Attribute("NonCommission").Value, _
                        .Rate = n.Element(ns + "Rates").Element(ns + "Rate").Attribute("Amount").Value, _
                        .CurrencyCode = n.Element(ns + "Rates").Element(ns + "Rate").Attribute("CurrencyCode").Value,
                        .TotalPrice = n.Element(ns + "Rates").Element(ns + "Rate").Element(ns + "HotelTotalPricing").Attribute("Amount").Value, _
                        .Disclaimer = n.Element(ns + "Rates").Element(ns + "Rate").Element(ns + "HotelTotalPricing").Element(ns + "Disclaimer").Value, _
                        .Surcharge = n.Element(ns + "Rates").Element(ns + "Rate").Element(ns + "HotelTotalPricing").Element(ns + "TotalSurcharges").Attribute("Amount").Value})
        Next
        Return _rates
    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrorMessage = ex.Message
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

Maybe someday I'll find a more efficient way to accomplish this

Answer (score 0):

If you've never dealt with LINQ to XML, you may find yourself struggling a bit at the beginning, but this should help you get there faster:

```vb
Dim xml As XDocument = XDocument.Parse("...") 'or XDocument.Load("...")
```

You can also assign a whole XML (or part thereof) into a variable AS IS, to test your concept, i.e. this is 100% valid syntax in VB10+ (~.NET 4.0+):

```vb
Dim xml As XDocument = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
                       <RoomRates>
                         <RoomRate>
                           <AdditionalInfo>
                             <Text>BLOOMBERG LP, 0.0 KM</Text>
                           </AdditionalInfo>
                           <Rates>
                             <Rate Amount="66.600" CurrencyCode="KWD"></Rate>
                           </Rates>
                         </RoomRate>
                       </RoomRates>
```

After that, here is what you can do:

```vb
Dim ns As XNamespace = "http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2003/07"
Dim roomRate As XElement = xml.Descendants(ns + "RoomRate").First

Dim additionalInfoText As String = roomRate.Descendants(ns + "Text").First
```

You can now inspect both `roomRate` and `additionalInfoText` in debugger, to see how it worked.

When in doubt about functionality of `XDocument/XElement`, please see relevant MSDN articles.

Comment: You're right I am struggling with this. It's a complex XML file and I'm struggling getting the attributes and elements into my class. Once I can get 1 in I can figure out how to loop through and get them all. Any help from anyone?

Comment: @PsychoCoder: The above did not help at all? If you have a question, feel free to ask. Without a question I cannot help you. To make the above code work, I pasted your XML as text into the code file, and added missing ending tags (to make it valid). I mean it's not just some code, it's the actual code for YOUR data, to showcase data retrieval mechanism using LINQ-to-XML. As you can imagine, I tested it to work in Visual Studio before posting here.

Comment: check my edit above, maybe that will clarify things more what I'm having issues with :)