# Parse html from a string in VB.NET using LINQ

Tags: html, vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml

I want to import the html from a web page and then parse it and retrieve http links from the elements. I am able to grab the html and put it in a string. Also, if I have the html in xml format, I am able to do a for each loop to retrieve the data. But I am not able to figure out how to take the html string and make it readable by LINQ. I think I'm missing some simple part here.

```
Sub GetTest()
        Dim source As String = "http://gd2.mlb.com/components/game/mlb/year_2018/month_03/day_29/"
        Dim Client As New WebClient
        Dim html As String = Client.DownloadString(source)

        Dim xml = XElement.Parse(html)

        Dim links = From link In xml...<a>

        For Each link In links
            MessageBox.Show(link.@href)
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: How is this different from [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48235007/1070452)?

Comment: My last question was answered. I was able to parse the xml from a different page. This one is html and it doesn't seem to work the same.

Comment: You should install HtmlAgilityPack via NuGet,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/516811/1070452

Comment: Html is not standard Xml. Things like unclosed tags `<br>` and also simple javascript expressions like `a < 5` can break the parser. That's why HtmlAgilityPack exists.

Comment: But the page I'm looking at seems to be good html without unclosed tags. I would prefer to avoid doing something super complex when a few lines of code will work just as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page can be parsed as Xml after getting rid of first unclosed tag:

```
Dim xml = XElement.Parse(html.Substring(html.IndexOf(">") + 1))
For Each link In xml.Descendants("a")
    Console.WriteLine(link.Attribute("href"))
Next
```

In general there are multiple issues when trying to parse Html as if it was standard Xml. So it is better to use HtmlAgilityPack.